# Get Result in Next Row in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a single Row in DataGridView which shows different results for the selected Oids..The problem is that the next result replaces the first one in the same row..Is there any way to get next result in next rows so that DataGridview can show previous results also..my datagrid is not bound to any data source.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim host As String
    Dim community As String
    host = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString
    community = DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value.ToString
    Dim txt4B As New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    txt4B.Value = "public"



    Dim result As Dictionary(Of Oid, AsnType)

    Dim requestOid() As String = Nothing

    Dim snmp As New SimpleSnmp
    snmp = New SimpleSnmp(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value.ToString)

    result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1, New String() {DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value.ToString()})


    If Not snmp.Valid Then

        MessageBox.Show("Invalid hostname/community")

    End If

    If result IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each kvp In result
            DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(kvp.Value.Type)
            DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = kvp.Key.ToString
            DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = kvp.Value.ToString()


        Next kvp
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No results received")
    End If

    DataGridView2.AutoResizeColumn(0)
    DataGridView2.AutoResizeColumn(1)
    DataGridView2.AutoResizeColumn(2)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

```
        DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(kvp.Value.Type)
        DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = kvp.Key.ToString
        DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = kvp.Value.ToString()
```

With something like this...

```
    Dim NewRow As New DataGridViewRow

    Dim Cell1 As DataGridViewCell

    Cell1.Value = SnmpConstants.GetTypeName(kvp.Value.Type)

    Dim Cell2 As DataGridViewCell

    Cell2.Value = kvp.Key.ToString()

    Dim Cell3 As DataGridViewCell

    Cell3.Value = kvp.Value.ToString()

    NewRow.Cells.Add(Cell1)
    NewRow.Cells.Add(Cell2)
    NewRow.Cells.Add(Cell3)

    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(NewRow)
```

This will create a new row with those values instead of overwriting the existing values.